# a sql question about linking tables

Tags: sql, mysql

I wonder why these statements are not the same (the first one worked for me)

```
AND user_thread_map.user_id = $user_id
AND user_thread_map.thread_id = threads.id

AND user_thread_map.user_id = users.id
AND user_thread_map.thread_id = threads.id
AND users.id = $user_id
```

Shouldn't they be the same? In the 2nd one I linked all the tables in the first 2 lines, then I tell it to select where users.id = $user_id.

Can someone explain why the 2nd statement doesn't work? Because I thought it would.

Comment: You should post the whole query and the table structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're getting no rows returned (you don't really say what the problem *is*, so I'm guessing a bit here), my first thought is that there are no rows in `users` where `id` is equal to `$user_id`.

That's the basic difference between those two SQL segments, the second is a cross-join of the `user_thread_map`, `threads` and `users` tables. The first does not join with `users` at all, so that's where I'd be looking for the problem.

It appears that your `user_thread_map` table is a many-to-many relationship between `users` and `threads`. If that is true, are you sure you have a foreign key constraint between the ID fields in that table to both corresponding other tables, something like:

```
users:
    id integer primary key
    name varchar(50)
threads:
    id integer primary key
    thread_text varchar(100)
user_thread_map:
    user_id integer references users(id)
    thread_id integer references threads(id)
```

If you have those foreign key constraints, it should be impossible to end up with a `user_thread_map(user_id)` value that doesn't have a corresponding `users(id)` value.

If those constraints aren't there, a query can tell you which values need to be fixed before *immediately adding the constraints (this is important to prevent the problem from re-occurring)*, something like:

```
select user_thread_map.user_id
from user_thread_map
left join users
on user_thread_map.user_id = users.id
where users.id is null
```

Comment: its really weird cause ive checked that foreign keys are applied on the user_thread_map table. have no clue why it didnt work. but i just picked the first one.

Answer (score 1):

The first one would select records from table `user_thread_map` with `user_id = $user_id`, irrespective of whether a record in table `user` existed with that id. The second query would only return something if the related record in `user` is found.